# Can't rename columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to rename columns in data frame from `Characteristics..genotype.` to `genotype` and from `Characteristics..age.` to `age`:

```
pData(raw_data) %>%
  rename(
    age = Characteristics..age.,
    genotype = Characteristics..genotype.
  )
```

I get the following error:

> Error in rename(., age = Characteristics..age., genotype = Characteristics..genotype.) : object 'Characteristics..age.' not found

Which doesn't make sense since columns exist in the data frame:

```
pData(raw_data)$Characteristics..genotype.
```

Output of the above:

> [1] N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q wt         wt         wt         N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q wt         wt
>   [12] wt         N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q N171-HD82Q wt         wt         wt
>   Levels: N171-HD82Q wt

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be backquotes

```
library(dplyr)
 pData(raw_data) %>%
  rename(
    age = `Characteristics..age.`,
   genotype = `Characteristics..genotype.`
  )
```

Or based on the error (reproduced with `plyr::rename`), it would be better to use `::` to specify the package from which it loads to avoid masking

```
pData(raw_data) %>%
  dplyr::rename(
    age = Characteristics..age.,
   genotype = Characteristics..genotype.
  )
```

But, while testing on `dplyr_0.8.3`, it is working fine without backquotes a well

```
data(mtcars)
raw_data <- head(mtcars)
names(raw_data)[1] <- "Characteristics..genotype."
raw_data %>%
      dplyr::rename(genotype = Characteristics..genotype.)
#             genotype cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# ...
```

The issue would be that `plyr` also include the same `rename` function, so if the package was also loaded, it could mask the `dplyr::rename`

```
raw_data %>% 
    plyr::rename(genotype = Characteristics..genotype.)
```

> Error in plyr::rename(., genotype = Characteristics..genotype.) :
>   unused argument (genotype = Characteristics..genotype.)

Comment: It was some other package masking `rename`, I used `dplyr::rename` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `rename_all` and do the renaming with a function, e.g. use `stringr::str_remove_all` to remove all instances of `"Characteristics.."` at the start or `"."` at the end (periods escaped with `\\`).

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr and stringr
df %>% 
  rename_all(str_remove_all, '^Characteristics\\.\\.|\\.$')
```